# Player rotates and flies in a direction instead of moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I halfway have no idea what I am doing. Trying to get the player to walk around but instead it rotates and then flies in the direction of the trigger instead. I don't know how to fix this. Here's my code, I hope someone can figure out whats going on cause I can't. It may be  a problem in the ridged body but again, no idea how to fix that

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    private Animator playerAnim;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float gravityModifier;
    public bool isOnGround = true;
    public bool gameOver = false;
    public ParticleSystem explosionParticle;
    public ParticleSystem dirkParticle;
    public AudioClip jumpSound;
    public AudioClip crashSound;
    private AudioSource playerAudio;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Physics.gravity *= gravityModifier;
        playerAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed * verticalInput);
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed * horizontalInput);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround) {
            playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isOnGround = false; //Makes sure you cannot jump in the air
            playerAnim.SetTrigger("Jump_trig");
            dirkParticle.Stop();
            playerAudio.PlayOneShot(jumpSound, 1.0f);
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `Rigidbody` to apply any force or velocity to the player, it doesn't appear as if the player is walking or running, it appears as if some external force is pushing the player in that direction. Hence, use `CharacterController` to move the player.

Add the `CharacterController` component to the player in the inspector. In the script, initialize the `CharacterController` and get a reference to that component

```
private CharacterController cc;

void Start() {
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
```

Move the player in `Update()` method.

```
void Update() {
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // move the cc
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
    cc.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```